# Attempting to input Dates into an ObservableList JavaFXML

Tags: string, date, javafx, observablelist

I'm attempting to input dates into a choicebox via an observable list

```
@FXML 

private void addDates(ActionEvent event){
    LocalDate startDate = BookingsStartBookingDate.getValue();
    LocalDate endDate = BookingsEndBookingDate.getValue();
    List<LocalDate> totalDates = new ArrayList<>();

    while (!startDate.isAfter(endDate)){
         totalDates.add(startDate);            
        startDate = startDate.plusDays(1);
    }

    ObservableList<LocalDate> oLocalDate = FXCollections.observableArrayList(totalDates);
    breakfastDateChoiceBox.setItems(oLocalDate);

}
```

I get the error saying that observablelist dates arent compatible with observablelists string.

Comment: Show where you declared `breakfastDateChoiceBox`

Comment: You are most probably declaring a `ChoiceBox<String> breakfastDateChoiceBox` and try to `setItems()` for `ObservableList<LocalDate>`.